# Jquery DataTables not showing page numbers correctly

Tags: datatables

I am using the latest version Jquery DataTables.net, and have a table that display a total of 10 records per page, with a max count of 1004.

However, in the info bar, this reads:

> Showing 1 to 5 of 1.004

[image]

the default of my table is as follows:

```
var oMessageDate = $("#messageDateDT").DataTable({
dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-12'<'pull-right'T><'pull-left'l>r<'clearfix'>>>t<'row'<'col-sm-12'<'pull-left'i><'pull-right'p><'clearfix'>>>",
stateSave: true,
pageLength: 10,
lengthMenu: [[5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]],
columns: [
    { data: "MessageReference", sWidth: "15%" },
    { data: "Beneficiary" },
    { data: "Currency", sWidth: "5%" },
    { data: "Amount" },
    { data: "MessageDate", sWidth: "15%" },
    { data: "MessageType", sWidth: "5%" },
    { data: "Direction", sWidth: "5%"},
    { data: "Assigned", sWidth: "10%" },
    { data: "Status", sWidth: "17%" },
    { data: "Message" },
    { data: "MessageId", sWidth: "5%" },
    { data: "StatusCode" }
],
"autoWidth": false,
"pagingType" :"full_numbers",
language: {
    "decimal": "-",
    "thousands": ".",
    "infoEmpty": "No entries to show",
    "lengthMenu": "Display _MENU_ records",
    "processing": "Loading data",
    searchPlaceholder: "on everything",
    "zeroRecords": "No records to display",
    "aria": {
        "sortAscending": ": activate to sort column ascending",
        "sortDescending": ": activate to sort column descending"
    }
},
"columnDefs": [
    { "visible": false, "targets": 9 },

    { "visible": false, "targets": 10 },
     { "visible": false, "targets": 11 }
]
```

});

Can you please advise, how I can correct this.

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot shows

> Showing 1 to **10** of 1.004 entries

And your default pageLength option is 10 which would give you 101 pages.

Comment: true, how silly of me. However, how do i fix the 1.004 decimal being shown.

Comment: That's a thousands-separator, you can change it in your `language` options.

Comment: Yes, I can, but that will effect the items in the table. I just want this 'Showing' number to show 1004

Comment: I don't think that is possible without going into the datatables code.